# sbt multi-project build with test dependency between projects?

Tags: scala, sbt

Say I have

```
lazy val foo = Project(
  id            = "foo",
  base          = file("foo")
)

lazy val bar = Project(
  id            = "bar",
  base          = file("bar")
  dependencies  = Seq(foo)    // only want that for `% "test"`....
)
```

How can I change `bar` so that it *only depends on foo in the test scope*?

Comment: Just a sidenote - under **SBT 0.13**, `foo` project can be defined by the `project` macro as follows: `lazy val foo = project`. Same for `bar`. Use `build.sbt` in this (simple) case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can say something like this: `foo % "test->test"`. This means test depends on test. You can have various other options like `foo % "test->test;compile->compile"` which means it depends not only on test but also on compile (compile -> compile). You can also have test depend on compile `foo % "test->compile"` and so on. It's described well [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project) in documentation.